# Removing a weird blue line from games in Bluestack

Tags: bluestacks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTjrT.jpg

I'm running a rooted Bluestacks and thought I'd check out some games to it, but...
There's a blue line at the top (as well as logo + name) that is annoying the hell out of me, and I've tried to remove it for ages now, but to no avail.. Anybody know what can be done here?

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Maybe a change in a line of code might be needed to help with my needs though..

Comment: irrelevant: you're not programming, you're just USING the software, therefore your question is off-topic.